# How to use "contains" with two arrays of objects

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have class Products

```
class Products {

    var name:String = ""
    var number:Int = 0

    init(name: String, number: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
    }
}
```

Then in view controller

```
var productFirst:[Products] = [Products(name: "First", number: 1)]
var productSecond:[Products] = [Products]()
```

I use productFirst to populate tableView.

I want to add selected row to productSecond and it works:

```
productSecond.append(productFirst[indexPath.row])
```

But I don't want to duplicate items in array, so I did

```
if !contains(productSecond, productFirst[indexPath.row]) {
    productSecond.append(productFirst[indexPath.row])
}
```

I get error. How to change it? When productFirst and productSeconds are just arrays of strings it works ok but now I need objects.

About error: First it is "could not find an overload for "!" that accepts the supplied arguments. After deleting exclamation mark it is "cannot invoke contains with an argument list of type '(@lvalue[Products,$T8)'

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: "I get error" does not describe a problem.

Comment: Of course, forgive me. First it is "could not find an overload for "!" that accepts the supplied arguments. After deleting exclamation mark it is "cannot invoke contains with an argument list of type '(@lvalue[Products,$T8)'

Comment: Instead of talking and showing little snippets, please reduce your code to a _reproducible_ and _complete_ example that someone else can cut from Stack Overflow and paste and try to compile themselves to see what the problem is. If you want help, be helpful about what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `contains()` function to work the `Products` class should implement `Equatable` protocol. That's the way only we can check whether two elements are equal.

```
class Products : Equatable {

    var name:String = ""
    var number:Int = 0

    init(name: String, number: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
    }
}

func ==(lhs: Products, rhs: Products) -> Bool
{
    return lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.number == rhs.number
}
```

Comment: Also, you don't need to define the `!=` operator as it derives its implementation from the standard library, which is handy.

Comment: Thank You, it works. I always did something like var elements = [1,2,3,4,5]
if contains(elements, 5) {
    println("yes")
}