# Swift Cannot invoke 'find' with an argument list of type '([Score], Score)' where Score is a struct

Tags: arrays, swift, find, indexof

While `find(["a", "b"], "c")` works with no problems, I get an error when trying to find the index of a structure inside an array of structures:

```
struct Score
{
    //...
}

var scores: [Score] = //...
var score: Score = //...

find(self.scores, score) // Error: Cannot invoke 'find' with an argument list of type '([Score], Score)'
```

I though it could be a problem with structures that can't be compared to each other by default. But changing `Score`s definition to `class`
 gives me the same error.

Comment: You have already found the reason. `Score` must implement the `Equatable` protocol (no matter if struct or class).

Comment: Probably the same issue as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887387/how-to-use-contains-with-two-arrays-of-objects

Answer (score 14, accepted):

EDIT: as of Swift 2.0, there is now a built-in version of `find` that takes a closure so you don’t have to write your own – but also, `find` has been renamed `indexOf`, and is now a protocol extension of `CollectionType`, so you call it like a method:

```
// if you make `Score` conform to `Equatable:
if let idx = self.scores.indexOf(score) {

}

// or if you don't make it Equatable, you can just use a closure:
// (see original answer below for why you might prefer to do this)
if let idx = scores.indexOf({$0.scoreval == 3}) {

}
```

Original pre-2.0 answer below

---

While the answers suggesting making your class `Equatable` may work nicely, I'd recommend a bit of caution before choosing to do this. The reason being that, as the docs state, equatability implies substitutability, and your `==` operator must be reflexive, symmetric and transitive. If you don't adhere to this, you might get some very weird behavior when using algorithms like `equals`, `sort` etc.  Be especially cautious if implementing `Equatable` on non-final classes. If you're sure you can meet requirements, go for it, and `find` will work.

If not, an alternative you could consider is writing a function that *ought* to be in the standard library but isn't, which is a `find` that takes a closure:

```
func find<C: CollectionType>(source: C, match: C.Generator.Element -> Bool) -> C.Index {
    for idx in indices(source) {
        if match(source[idx]) { return idx }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Once you have this, you can supply any matching criteria you prefer. For example, if your objects are classes you could use reference equality:

```
let idx = find(scores) { $0 === $1 }
```

Comment: It seems that `indexOf` has been renamed to `index(of:)` in Swift 3.

Answer (score 7):

The interface for the function `find` is/was:

```
func find<C : CollectionType where C.Generator.Element : Equatable>(domain: C,
    value: C.Generator.Element) -> C.Index?
```

This says that the `CollectionType` of `C` must have elements that are `Equatable` and, furthermore, that the `value` must also be `Equatable`.

[**Note Swift 3.0**: As of Swift 3.0, you'll need to use the `index` function which comes in two variations.  In the first, you'll supply your own predicate:

```
func index(where: (Self.Generator.Element) -> Bool) -> Self.Index?
```

In the second, your elements need to be equatable:

```
// Where Generator.Element : Equatable
func index(of: Self.Generator.Element) -> Self.Index?
```

If you decide to go the `equatable` route, then the following applies.
**Note End**]

Your `Score` struct is not `Equatable` and hence the error.  **You'll need to figure out what it means for scores to be equal to one another.**  Maybe it is some numerical 'score'; maybe it is a 'score' and a 'user id'.  It depends on your `Score` abstraction.  Once you know, you implement `==` using:

```
func == (lhs:Score, rhs:Score) -> Bool {
 return // condition for what it means to be equal
}
```

Note: if you use `class` and thus scores have 'identity' then you can implement this as:

```
func == (lhs:Score, rhs:Score) -> Bool { return lhs === rhs }
```

Your example with strings works because `String` is `Equatable`.  If you look in the Swift library code you'll see:

```
extension String : Equatable {}
func ==(lhs: String, rhs: String) -> Bool
```

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said, the objects you search for must conform to the Equatable protocol.

So you need to add an extension to your Score struct that tells the compiler that it conforms to that protocol:

```
extension Score: Equatable {}
```

And then you need to implement the == function for that class:

```
public func ==(lhs: Score, rhs: Score) -> Bool
{
  return lhs.whatever == rhs.whatever //replace with code for your struct.
}
```

Comment: Why do I get the same error when making `Score` a `class` instead? Isn't `==` valid for classes?

Comment: No. == is not valid for any custom object unless you define it as outlined in my answer.