# How to remove an element of a given custom type value from an array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I want to remove element of custom type value from an array.

I want to pass a variant instance to function to remove it from array, I don't want to use removeAtIndex().

```
var favoriteVariants: [Variant]

func removeVariant(variant: Variant)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Variant` is `Equatable` and you only want to remove the first one that matches:

```
if let idx = favoriteVariants.indexOf(variant) {
    favoriteVariants.removeAtIndex(idx)
}
```

If it isn’t `Equatable` and you have some other matching criteria to find just one to remove:

```
let idx = favoriteVariants.indexOf {
   // match $0 to variant
}

if let idx = idx {
    favoriteVariants.removeAtIndex(idx)
}
```

(these are assuming Swift 2.0 – if 1.2, it’s `find(favoriteVariants, variant)` instead of `indexOf`, and there isn’t a version that takes a closure, though it’s not too hard to [write one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29719500/3925941))

If there are multiple ones you want to remove in one go:

```
favoriteVariants = favoriteVariants.filter {
    // criteria to _keep_ any given favorite
}
```

All of these could be wrapped in extensions if what you want to do is general enough to justify it.

Comment: User need not use " i don't want to use removeAtIndex()." But your using

Comment: I took that to mean, “I don’t have the index” (so gave a way to find it) rather than an arbitrary constraint to avoid using a method for no reason.

Comment: Thanks Airspeed Velocity, i'm using swift 1.2 now and i got this when used find. Connot invoke 'find' with an argument list of type '([Varaint], Variant)'